# How to pull a specific branch from Github

Tags: git, github, branch

There is this repo :

https://github.com/googlesamples/android-architecture

And there is this branch :

https://github.com/googlesamples/android-architecture/tree/todo-mvvm-databinding/

I have clone the project but i have only the master. What can i do to get this branch ?

Answer (score 51, accepted):

If you did a clone, then all branches should be available to you. You need to checkout the branch.

`git checkout todo-mvvm-databinding`

If the branch isn't available for whatever reason, then you can create it and then pull it:

`git checkout -b todo-mvvm-databinding` (`-b` specifies "create branch")

`git pull origin todo-mvvm-databinding` will fetch and merge this branch into your local one.

Answer (score 4):

The above answer works well but I wanted to post with `fetch` and `checkout` which works fine as well.

Step 1: `git fetch todo-mvvm-databinding`

Step 2: `git checkout todo-mvvm-databinding`

You are on your `todo-mvvm-databinding` branch.

Comment: you can use `git fetch origin todo-mvvm-databinding`

Answer (score 4):

Most of those above methods works but I would like to present this approach which worked well for me.

Step 1: List all remote branches that are available

```
git fetch
git branch -r
```

The out put may look as shown below depending on available remote branches for your project.

```
origin/HEAD -> origin/master
origin/develop
origin/feature/modular_approach
origin/master
```

Step 2:

Make sure to commit all your changes on the current branch as git will throw some errors and warning about uncommited codes.
Select a branch and run this command.

```
git checkout origin/feature/modular_approach
```

Answer (score 2):

If the branch you want to retrieve does not exist locally but is present on the remote.

Create a branch with exactly the same name as your local remote branch

```
git checkout name_remote_branch
```

Make a pull on this new branch

```
git pull
```